# WPF virtualization alternative

Tags: wpf, virtualization, scrollviewer

Is there a WPF virtualization alternative where the containers for all items are generated (so bindings are evaluated), but are collapsed while not in view (so no rendering/layouting overhead)?

Virtualization means, that no containers are generated for the items that are not in view. However, I need some additional functionality which is triggered by some (attached) dependency property within the item containers. I have profiled the application with virtualization disabled, and found that the main bottleneck is the layout pass and the rendering. Having virtualization turned on, the performance significantly improves, but as expected the binding does not update for the items that are not in view.

My idea would be to have an alternative ScrollViewer that automatically collapses all items that are not in view (and makes them visible again when in view), but still displays the thumb at the expected position (and with the expected height).

Does anyone know an existing solution for this?

Comment: What functionality do you need that is related to a dependency property ? You have all the items in the viewmodel can't you use the objects there to get what you want ?

Comment: I would like to have the functionality within some GridView component. It automatically manages grouping and sorting of the items (the ViewModel is not involved), however it does not update the grouping/sorting if some property in the ViewModel changes. I can detect the change via an attached property - however, this only works if the corresponding cells are created.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this issues is to rely on the MVVM pattern. All *dependencies* will be managed on the Model/ViewModel but **not** on the View side

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. However, I have to disagree: When there is some functionality that can be "universally" handled by changing only one style of some WPF component - why should I do it maybe 20 times in all ViewModels that are consumed? I think this would be very error-prone.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you mean by 20 times. In practice the ViewModel could just inherit another ViewModel so you make only 1 change. Reasoning about how it shows VS how data changes looks more error prone to me. But again I guess it is because I'm more used to the later.

Comment: The ViewModels have absolutely nothing in common, except that these are lists of objects which are presented using some (external) GridView component. The component already supports Grouping/Sorting, but does not update this if some property of the ViewModel (or any child which is bound to some column of the GridView) changes. So inheritance is not really an option...